# What is considered a cubic algorithm when considering time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time, complexity-theory, cubic

So I've implemented this algorithm and after analyzing its time complexity I've found that its upper bound is restricted by O(n^2*m) where n is the number of vertices in a graph and m is the number of edges. I'm wondering if this would be considered a cubic algorithm? I know that O(n^3) is cubic but due to the "m" I'm not sure. Anyone that can explain if it is cubic or some other type of complexity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graph algorithms present a special case regarding time complexity, Technically, O(n^2*m) is *quartic* (O(n^4)), since m = O(n^2). However, since many graph algorithms are sensitive to the number of edges, we report the complexity as a function of vertices and edges separately, to reflect that sensitivity. If the graph is sparse (with m = O(n)), then O(n^2m) is cubic, but for denser graphs, it behaves more like a quartic algorithm.

Comment: Alright I suspected that, the worst case is the complete graph of course. Alright I need to redo some things, thanks!